# historical annual average temperature by country (with data after 2016)

Tags: data-request, geospatial

has anyone come across a data set of *all* countries with historical average annual temperatures? The World Bank provided exactly this (see [here](https://climateknowledgeportal.worldbank.org/download-data)), but has not updated it after 2016 - I would like to have the latest data until 2019.

Answer (score 0):

**[Monthly Climatic Data for the World](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/IPS/mcdw/mcdw.html)**

[image]

Monthly issues of this publication from May of 1948 through the present contain monthly mean temperature, pressure, precipitation, vapor pressure, and sunshine recorded at approximately 2,000 surface data collection stations around the world. It also offers monthly mean upper air temperatures, dew point depressions, and wind velocities for approximately 500 observing sites. Each issue represents the final quality-controlled data from all stations: issues generally become available after a 4 - 6-month time lag.

**Where do these data come from?**

Data are prepared by Members of the World Meteorological Organization (WMO) and exchanged monthly via international telecommunications systems. The National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration's (NOAA) National Centers for Environmental Prediction (NCEP) and the United Kingdom's Hadley Centre for Climate Prediction and Research prepares and relays data to NOAA's National Centers for Environmental Information for quality control, publication, and archive.

Contains monthly mean temperature, pressure, precipitation, vapor pressure, and sunshine for approximately 2,000 surface data collection stations worldwide and monthly mean upper air temperatures, dew point depressions, and wind Velocities for approximately 500 observing sites.

Data 1948 to 2018 December - **[Download Here](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/IPS/mcdw/mcdw.html)**

---